# How to get the color of a seaborn/matplotlib bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am building a seaborn graphics with this code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
df=pd.DataFrame(data=['a','b','c','d','a','a','b','c','a','a'],columns['datos'])
tabla=df['datos'].value_counts().reset_index()
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
sns.set()
sns.barplot(x='index', y='datos', data=tabla, ax=ax1)
```

It does work properly....but How could I get the code of the colors used for every bar?
I have tried with :

```
f.get_color()
ax.get_color()
```

but no success at all...

thanks in advance
waly

Answer (score 4):

I admit it's an ugly way, but you will need to access the children of your plot. Note that this probably won't work if you plot more than just the countplot, since you will get all used Rectangle colors in your plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
sns.set()

df=pd.DataFrame(data=['a','b','c','d','a','a','b','c','a','a'],columns=['datos'])
tabla=df['datos'].value_counts().reset_index()
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
sns.barplot(x='index', y='datos', data=tabla, ax=ax1)

bars = [r for r in ax1.get_children() if type(r)==Rectangle]
colors = [c.get_facecolor() for c in bars[:-1]] # I think the last Rectangle is the background.
```

Comment: Thanks pask!..it works!...I wanted to include an additional graphic with just 'c' and 'd' counts but using the same colours than the previous..so that's why I needed to get both : 'colors[2:]'....thanks!